# concatenate text to create math that can be calculated

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm not sure if the title is descriptive enough! I've used the CONCATENATE formula to create the following:

```
=$'2022'.a17
```

It goes like this:

```
=CONCAT("=$'";TEXT(A20;"YYMM");"'.a17")
```

When I type the aforementioned text it brings up the contents of cell A17 in sheet '2022'.
When I create the text with the formula, although it's exactly the same, no calculation can be done. Is there any way to force calc to calculate this equation?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [**INDIRECT()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060109.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3153181)? Like as `=INDIRECT(CONCAT("$'";TEXT(A20;"YYMM");"'.A17"))`?

Comment: @JohnSUN unfortunately it does not work (#REF!)

Comment: `=INDIRECT("$Sheet1.A17")` does work for me, check your formula. LibreOffice 6.4.7.2

Comment: @user1479272 It may well be if your spreadsheet does not have a sheet named **2022**. [**Here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52kmedgp04j6sbz/indirect_by_year_month.ods?dl=0) is my example.

Comment: @JohnSUN You're right... The problem was with the quotation ('). I removed it and it works! Thanks a lot!